# Laravel 'User' model no id column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting an error when trying to Auth::attempt() with the User model saying that I do not have a 'id' column in my table. I am using the 'username' field as the primary key in my table and I didn't want to make an int 'id' column as the primary key. Is there anyway I can change the primary key column in the User model?

Error:

[image]

My user model:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


        public function getRememberToken()
        {
            return $this->remember_token;
        }   

        public function setRememberToken($remember_token) 
        {
            $this->remember_token   =   $remember_token;
        }

        public function getRememberTokenName()
        {
            return 'remember_token';
        }

        public function isAdmin()
        {
            return $this->isAdmin   ==  1;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the primary key used to search you must define the `primaryKey` property on the User model.

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
...
```

Now laravel will use the username column as the primary key column.

See the below quote from the laravel documentation.

> Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key
>   column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this
>   convention.

-- [Eloquent - Basic Usage](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage)